# What is the red-minus icon in Egit conflict?

Tags: eclipse, egit, git-merge-conflict

I have this strange icon in EGit, I don't know the meaning of this icon.
I have looked in https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State, but I haven't found it.

[image: EGit conflict unknown icon]

The particular thing of this icon is that the option "merge tool" can't be choosed.

What's the meaning of this icon?

Comment: Is the file deleted on one side or maybe both sides?

Comment: I have made a pull from remote; the files are new and they are "newcomers" in my local repository...